# Need help clearing text area after JavaScript function is ran again

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, textarea

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\style.css" />
         
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <!-- || HEADER || -->

      <header>
        <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      </header>

      <!-- || CONTENT || -->

      <div class="card">

        <div class="card-header">
          <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <textarea readonly id="password" placeholder="Your Secure Password" aria-label="Generated Password"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
          <button id="copy" class="btn-copy">Copy to Clipboard</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- || JAVASCRIPT STYLE SHEET || -->
    
    <script src="assets\js\script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

---- || JavaScript || ----

```
// GenerateBtn
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Define variables
var selectLowerCase;
var selectUpperCase;
var selectNumber;
var selectSpecial;

// Set variables  
var plength = 0;
var lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
// Uppercase conversion
var upperCase = lowerCase.toUpperCase();
var numbers = "1234567890";
var specialCharacter = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@][^_`{|}~'<=>";
var userPassword = "";
var passwordGroup = "";

// Function writes password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  passwordText.value = password;
}

// Clicking btn runs funtion
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

// Request length of the password
var plength = parseInt(prompt("Welcome to Password Generator 2020. To begin, please enter a length of your password from 8-128.",""));

// Require number
while (isNaN(plength)) {
var plength = parseInt(prompt("This is not a number. Please enter a number between 8 - 128.",""));
} 

// Require length    
while (plength < 8 || plength > 128) {
var plength = parseInt(prompt("Enter length of password.* Length must be between 8 - 128 characters",""));
} 

// Confirm lower case letters 
var selectLowerCase = confirm("Use lower case letters?");
// Confirm upper case letters
var selectUpperCase = confirm("Use upper case letters?");
//Confirm numeric characters 
var selectNumber = confirm("Use numbers?");
//Confirm special characters
var selectSpecial = confirm("Use special characters?");

// Call function to generate password 
generatePassword();

// Write generated password on page
document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = userPassword; 

// From selected options randomly generate password.
function generatePassword() {
  if (selectLowerCase) {
  passwordGroup += lowerCase;
  }
  if (selectUpperCase) {
  passwordGroup += upperCase;
  }
  if (selectNumber) {
  passwordGroup += numbers;
  }
  if (selectSpecial) {
  passwordGroup += specialCharacter;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < plength; i++) {
    userPassword += passwordGroup.charAt(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordGroup.length)
    );
  }
  return userPassword;
}

/* || COPY FUNCTION || */

// https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp
var copy = document.querySelector("#copy");
copy.addEventListener("click", function () {
  copyPassword();
});
function copyPassword() {
    document.getElementById("password").select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
}
```

What I want it to do is wait to run the prompts till after the page loads and you click the generate button. Then when clicking the generate button again I want it to clear the text area and repeat the prompts. Currently, it's asking the prompts when the page loads then running the function again with the same prompts originally chosen and adding them to the text previously in the text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the pop-up only when the button "Generate Password" is clicked, you should insert all the pop-ups in the `writePassword` function:

```
   function writePassword() {
        
        // Request length of the password
        plength = parseInt(prompt("Welcome to Password Generator 2020. To begin, please enter a length of your password from 8-128.", ""));
    
        // Require number
        while (isNaN(plength)) {
            plength = parseInt(prompt("This is not a number. Please enter a number between 8 - 128.", ""));
        }
    
        // Require length    
        while (plength < 8 || plength > 128) {
            plength = parseInt(prompt("Enter length of password.* Length must be between 8 - 128 characters", ""));
        }
    
        // Confirm lower case letters 
        selectLowerCase = confirm("Use lower case letters?");
        // Confirm upper case letters
        selectUpperCase = confirm("Use upper case letters?");
        //Confirm numeric characters 
        selectNumber = confirm("Use numbers?");
        //Confirm special characters
        selectSpecial = confirm("Use special characters?");
    
        var password = generatePassword();
        document.querySelector("#password").value = password;
        
    }
```

Then, in order to clear the password area you should simply set the `userPassword` variable to a null string before you start generating a new password (since you append the random generated characters):

```
function generatePassword() {
    userPassword = "";
    if (selectLowerCase) {
        passwordGroup += lowerCase;
    }
    if (selectUpperCase) {
        passwordGroup += upperCase;
    }
    if (selectNumber) {
        passwordGroup += numbers;
    }
    if (selectSpecial) {
        passwordGroup += specialCharacter;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < plength; i++) {
        userPassword += passwordGroup.charAt(
            Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordGroup.length)
        );
    }
    return userPassword;
}
```

This is the complete JavaScript code:

```
   // GenerateBtn
    var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
    
    // Define variables
    var selectLowerCase;
    var selectUpperCase;
    var selectNumber;
    var selectSpecial;
    
    // Set variables  
    var plength = 0;
    var lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    // Uppercase conversion
    var upperCase = lowerCase.toUpperCase();
    var numbers = "1234567890";
    var specialCharacter = "!#$%&'()*+,-./:;?@][^_`{|}~'<=>";
    var userPassword = "";
    var passwordGroup = "";
    var plength;
    var selectLowerCase;
    var selectUpperCase;
    var selectNumber;
    var selectSpecial;
    
    // Function writes password to the #password input
    function writePassword() {
        
        // Request length of the password
        plength = parseInt(prompt("Welcome to Password Generator 2020. To begin, please enter a length of your password from 8-128.", ""));
    
        // Require number
        while (isNaN(plength)) {
            plength = parseInt(prompt("This is not a number. Please enter a number between 8 - 128.", ""));
        }
    
        // Require length    
        while (plength < 8 || plength > 128) {
            plength = parseInt(prompt("Enter length of password.* Length must be between 8 - 128 characters", ""));
        }
    
        // Confirm lower case letters 
        selectLowerCase = confirm("Use lower case letters?");
        // Confirm upper case letters
        selectUpperCase = confirm("Use upper case letters?");
        //Confirm numeric characters 
        selectNumber = confirm("Use numbers?");
        //Confirm special characters
        selectSpecial = confirm("Use special characters?");
    
        var password = generatePassword();
        document.querySelector("#password").value = password;
        
    }
    
    // Clicking btn runs funtion
    generate.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
    
    
    // Call function to generate password 
    generatePassword();
    
    // Write generated password on page
    document.getElementById("password").innerHTML = userPassword;
    
    // From selected options randomly generate password.
    function generatePassword() {
        userPassword = "";
        if (selectLowerCase) {
            passwordGroup += lowerCase;
        }
        if (selectUpperCase) {
            passwordGroup += upperCase;
        }
        if (selectNumber) {
            passwordGroup += numbers;
        }
        if (selectSpecial) {
            passwordGroup += specialCharacter;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < plength; i++) {
            userPassword += passwordGroup.charAt(
                Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordGroup.length)
            );
        }
        return userPassword;
    }
    
    /* || COPY FUNCTION || */
    
    // https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp
    var copy = document.querySelector("#copy");
    copy.addEventListener("click", function() {
        copyPassword();
    });
    
    function copyPassword() {
        document.getElementById("password").select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        alert("Password copied to clipboard!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try refactoring your code**

Make a separate function for all your prompts.

Call the function when the DOM is completely loaded.

And at the starting of the function always set the value of your password textarea to empty.